# How to conditionally add a data attribute to a div in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My Code:

```
<div>Something Here</div>
```

When the condition is true, eg: data.nextDiv == true

The code will be changed as follow:

```
<div myattr >Something Here</div>
```

My attempt:

```
<div ng-attr-myattr ="{{data.nextDiv == true ? null : null}}" >Something Here</div>
```

BUT, FAIL,  'myattr' is still printed out even the condition is false.

Anyone could help?

Comment: you also pass null if condition are false